# wipers will only run on one speed

Tags: windshield-wipers

Where is the wiper relay located on 1997 f150? My wipers only work on one speed. The windshield washer works well. I already replaced the switch, old switch handle was broke. The wipers still don't work. I can not locate the relay. I believe that would be the next step

Answer (score 2):

Its located in the Power Distribution Box in the engine compartment, Relay position 3 in the image below

.[image]

Comment: Is it possible to visually inspect a relay and see whether it is good or bad? like fuses? or we need to take them to an electronic shop?

Comment: Just replace it, they are fairly inexpensive.